# Replace canvas img when element is selected / unselected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a filter on a canvas (and over an image) when the user clicks the item in a list as follows:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" id="\''.$filters[$i].'\'" onclick="selectFilter(\''.$filters[$i].'\')">
    <img class="filter" id="\''.$filters[$i].'\'" src="pictures/filters/'.$filters[$i].'"/>
</div>
```

Which translates to an easier to read (console when inspecting the page in a browser):

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" id="'mask1.png'" onclick="selectFilter('mask1.png')">
    <img class="filter" id="'mask1.png'" src="pictures/filters/'mask1.png'"/>
</div>
<div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" id="'mask2.png'" onclick="selectFilter('mask2.png')">
    <img class="filter" id="'mask2.png'" src="pictures/filters/'mask2.png'"/>
</div>

//...
```

What I am trying to do here is to pass the selected filter name to the `img` displayed over the canvas:

```
<img class="filter_img" id="filter_image" src="/pictures/filters/(selected filter name)">
```

I am struggling with the selection of the filter in the list, I am trying to change the div `id` when the user selects it to remember which filters is "selected" (and later unselect it and select another) and then pass the corresponding name as a source to load the img:

```
function selectFilter(filter_name)
{
    document.getElementById(filter_name).id = "selected_filter";
    document.getElementById(filter_image).src = "/pictures/filters/" + "filter_name";
}
```

The issue is that I can't get any `id` or `src` to change..
I am getting a `Cannot set property 'id' of null`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to select an element with id `mask1.png`,

but the id of your elements is `'mask1.png'` including the `'`-characters.

so `getElementById` cant find your element.

Same thing goes for mask2.png. `getElementById` cant find your elements and returns null. You cant set id of `null`, and thats what your error tells you:  `Can't set property 'id' of null.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer DigitalJedi! I thought about it and tried to add the `'` without success, could you show me how to do it? But isn't the `'` only showing in the HTML? The "easier to read" part of the code I included is what the console shows when inspecting the page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2dwyq1v/ 
if you are calling the function selectFilter with parameter "mask1.png", then the id you are looking for via getElementById() must also be "mask1.png". it must be EXACTLY the same. not with '- char included. Morover you should not have two elements with the same id